# Reconstruct a curve from its curvature and torsion

Tags: differential-geometry

Given two smooth functions $k(s)$ and $\tau(s)$, how can we construct a curve in $R^3$ that its curvature is $k$ and torsion is $\tau$? Is there any conditions that $k$ and $\tau$ must satisfy as the curvature and torsion of a curve? It seems to be a very natural question, but not an easy task.

Comment: Check any textbook in elementary differential geometry

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev I agree with the sentiment that the answer to this question is very well known, but I have half a dozen differential geometry textbooks and not one of them answers this question.  Even the relevant wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_curves) contains no references.  It seems that the geometry of curves has become so standard that modern books don't really bother with it any more and you have to consult older books.

Comment: @PaulSiegel Probably, because it's obvious nowadays, and the proof is given in Wikipedia: (1) Solve Frenet equations (existence & uniqueness for linear ODE); (2) prove that the solutions are orthonormal frames (uniqueness for ODE); (3) integrate $\tau$. E.g., Manfredo P. Do Carmo, Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces.

Comment: Alex is right, this is pretty easy as stated. I would just like to say that if we require the curve to be closed, then the problem is interesting.

Comment: There is some relevant discussion in the earlier MO question, [Existence and Properties of 3D Curves with unusual 2D (κ(s),τ(s)) Trajectories](http://mathoverflow.net/q/153567/6094).